# Data Vault Modelling Foreign Keys

Tags: data-modeling, data-vault

I have a question regarding specific data vault modelling.
I have a source table which captures call center CALL informations like this:
CallId (business key)
Date
Call_alert
Call_acw 
etc
The same source table also has a bunch of foreign keys in it, like this:
RouteID (on which line the call eventually ends)
ConnectionType (phone, email etc)

Via each foreign key it is possible to retrieve extra-information about the key (which is not linked to the CALL).

My question is how to model these foreign keys in my model? Do i keep them as attributes in my satellite or do i model them as links? Or any other option i haven't thought about?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

I'll focus on one example you give (RouteID) but the discussion is probably the same for each.

The first thing to remember is that the aim in Data Vault is to model the business and business processes not the system the data is stored in. Foreign keys may be an indication of something meaningful (a linking between two hubs) or they may not (the product of normalisation within the database that you may not need to replicate).

The first step in your case is to think about what RouteID and the data it links through to means to the business. If route (or the line it represents) is a meaningful concept to the business in its own right then it probably requires it's own hub, satellites for data relating to it and then link tables to join it up to your call data.

On the other hand the data might only have meaning as categorisation of another hub (call in your case) in which case think about de-normalising it in to a satellite that connects to the call hub. Remember that you can have multiple satellites connected to one hub, there's nothing preventing you having a call route satellite, a connection type satellite and so on.

You'll need to make this decision for each foreign key and probably end up with different choices for each. Staff member receiving the call for example would almost certainly be a link to another hub as you almost certainly have other data you want to link staff to. Something like the connection type you mention is unlikely to be meaningful in its own right so is more likely to form part of a satellite.